# Who is "her" in Al Ahzab 33:37?

Tags: quran, tafseer, surat-al-ahzab

I want to ask who is the "her" mentioned in Al Ahzab 33:37?

> And [remember, O Muhammad], when you said to the one on whom Allah bestowed favor and you bestowed favor, "Keep your wife and fear Allah," while you concealed within yourself that which Allah is to disclose. And you feared the people, while Allah has more right that you fear Him. So when Zayd had no longer any need for her, We married her to you in order that there not be upon the believers any discomfort concerning the wives of their adopted sons when they no longer have need of them. And ever is the command of Allah accomplished.
>
> <sub>[Qur'an 33:37](https://quran.com/33/37)</sub>

Kindly attach as many reliable sources for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

The verse is referring to [Zaynab bint Jahsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaynab_bint_Jahsh), who was at the time married to [Zayd ibn Harithah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zayd_ibn_Harithah). You may refer to [Tafsir al-Jalalayn](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=74&tSoraNo=33&tAyahNo=37&tDisplay=yes&UserProfile=0&LanguageId=2) for more information.

Comment: Are there any other sources that tell the same answer?

Comment: @Rextia you will hardly find a source that tells a different story!

Comment: We'll see about that