# Who was the biological mother of Zaynab bint Jahsh according to Muslim Scholars?

Tags: history

Continuing from these questions [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47386/who-is-her-in-al-ahzab-3337/47387?noredirect=1#comment80775_47387) and [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47591/how-do-we-know-that-her-in-3337-does-not-refer-to-zaynab-bint-jahsh?noredirect=1#comment81177_47591)

I want to know who was the biological Mother of [Zaynab bint Jahsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaynab_bint_Jahsh) ?

Is it really  [Umaima bint Abdulmuttalib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umama_bint_Abdulmuttalib)? What are the sources that say so?

What references say it is another person and not Umaima bint Abdulmuttalib?

Always put the reference to your answer. I got mine from wikipedia so not quite appropriate as an official / academic reference but good as a starting point.

Regards

Comment: I wonder if this is on-topic, The mother of Zaynab bint Jahsh has nothing to do with the teaching of Islam.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the lineage of a person with no clear connection to Islamic teachings or practices.

Comment: hah, has nothing to do? are you 100% sure? I'm telling you these questions there is a clear purpose and clear connection to a certain aspect of Islamic Teaching, you just don't see it now..it's a series of questions intended for a purpose....Should I ask these in General History section instead of asking it in an Islamic Section? And you think that will be appropriate?

Comment: @Rextia, this is forum is for discussing teachings of Islam. If your question is n topic, then provide the connection. Otherwise, you are free to ask anywhere else that will provide you answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, as it stands the question does not seem to relate to the teachings of Islam, if you clarify how it does in your question body, then i'll withdraw my vote.

Comment: I can tell you where these questions will lead & where the connection is to a certain ruling of Islam and what it can shed light to...but then if you know the objective, I fear you will answer it subjectively instead of answering it objectively which is what I'm aiming for...I can promise you these questions does indeed will relate to a certain teaching of Islam...and I will link these questions together so that you can draw a conclusion...at the end..of what this is all about. In other words, at the end it will be clear what it's for..

Comment: But if it's still not clear at the end when the final question is ask, then you can vote to close it down..doesn't have to be now if you want to vote to close it down, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think it's really that hard to guess where this is all going... the purpose is to clear (as clear as possible) some of the misconceptions that I found many people have related to a certain ruling of Islam..the answer to each of these questions creates a strong basis for the answer of my final question...so I had to give each question its own chance to be verified, reviewed and not putting all these questions together on the same page..because each one deserves its own moment. Its own chance..Thus when viewing it as a theme, these does and will relate to a certain teaching of Islam..

Comment: I understand some people needs to know the "real purpose" behind a question before trying to answer it and It feels almost like a real need. But that mindset can destroy the main criteria the person who posted the question wants when answering his question i.e. being objective. Then you actually don't really need to know the purpose of the question in order to answer the question that is being asked, unless the question itself wasn't clear about what it is asking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ibn Kathir in his history writes:

> بزينب بنت جحش بن رئاب بن يعمر بن صبرة بن مرة بن كبير بن غنم بن دودان بن أسد بن خزيمة الأسدية أم المؤمنين ، **وهي بنت أميمة بنت عبد المطلب عمة رسول الله** صلى الله عليه وسلم ، وكانت قبله عند مولاه زيد بن حارثة رضي الله عنه
>
> Zaynab bint Jahsh bin Riyab bin Ya'mur bin Sabra bin Murra Bin Kabir Bin Ghanam Bin Dudan Bin Asad Bin Khuzayma, Al-Asadiyya, The Mother of the Believers. And **she is the daughter of Umayma bint Abdul-Muttalib, the paternal aunt of the Messenger of Allah** ﷺ, and before him she was married to his freed slave, Zayd bin Harithah.
>
> <sup>— [The beginning and the End ( البداية والنهاية ) by Ibn Kathir](https://archive.org/stream/alhelawy07/bn06#page/n150/mode/2up)</sup>

The same is mentioned in several other works of *seerah*, *tarikh* and *tafsir* ; some don't mention a name  but do say that Zaynab was the daughter of the Prophet's paternal aunt.

I am not aware of any references that dispute this or say that it was "another person".