# Who was the biological mother of Umama (or Umayma) bint Abdul Muttalib?

Tags: history

Continuing from this question [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47740/who-was-the-biological-mother-of-zaynab-bint-jahsh-according-to-muslim-scholars?noredirect=1#comment81447_47740)

I would like to ask, according to Muslim Scholars, who was the biological mother of [Umama (or Umayma) bint Abdul Muttalib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umama_bint_Abdulmuttalib)?

What are the most legitimate / authorized source(s) that say that it is [Fatimah bint Amr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatimah_bint_Amr)?

What are the sources that says: no it is another person?

Please attach the reference in your answer.

Comment: It seems like this question would benefit from changing "What are the sources that says: no it is another person?" (which seems at odds with the request for "legitimate / authorized source(s)") to simply "Is this accurate?", i.e., it's a question of verifying the correctness of Wikipedia's claim (or just delete it, because the question has the same meaning without it).

Comment: oh no, you misunderstand, I'm not trying to verify the correctness of wikipedia. I never hold or claim wikipedia as a reliable source for this. It was just to give a chance to both positions, the ones who are "againts" this claim and the ones who are "for" it. It was just to be openly fair enough without being, myself,  in one of those positions in the first place i.e. I leave it you guys.

Comment: It'll get the same answer regardless, but it avoids the unnecessary [confrontational attitude](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/are-defend-yourself-style-posts-ever-constructive).

Comment: @Rebecca J. Stones. "It'll get the same answer regardless" you're concluding things to quickly. I'm telling you, what I'm doing, IS the real form of "genuine curiosity".

Comment: Ok I deleted the part where it says wikipedia. Done. Stating that was unnecessary. But to delete the question "What are the sources that says: no it is another person?" This I cannot. It's an indirect statement that I'm not in a pre determined position. There's no other way around it. I have to ask it. It is to be fair to other position. As I said, I have to be open and as objective as I can about this. The goal is not to confront, rather it is to eliminate the doubts as much as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Her father *[Abdul-Muttalib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdul-Muttalib)* was the grandfather of the Prophet, being the father of *Abdullah*.

Regarding her mother, Tabari narrates the following tradition from Hisham bin Muhammad:

> عبد الله بن عبد المطلب أبو رسول الله، وأبو طالب - واسمه عبد مناف - والزبير، وعبد الكعبة، وعاتكة، وبرة، و**أميمة**، ولد عبد المطلب إخوة، **أم جميعهم فاطمة بنت عمرو** بن عائذ ابن عمران بن مخزوم بن يقظة
>
> Abdullah bin Abdul-Mutallib the father of the Messenger of Allah, Abu Talib - whose name was Abd Manaf - Al-Zubayr, Abd Kaabah, Atikah, Barrah and **Umaymah**: these children of Abdul-Mutallib, were full brothers and sisters, **the mother of all of them was Fatimah bint Amr** bin A'idh bin Imran bin Makhzum bin Yaqazah.
>
> <sup>— [The History of the Prophets and Kings ( تاريخ الرسل والملوك ) by Tabari](https://archive.org/stream/trm01/trm02#page/n237/mode/2up)</sup>

Similar is related in the Seerah of Ibn Hisham:

> وأم عبد الله ، وأبي طالب ، والزبير ، **وجميع النساء غير صفية : فاطمة بنت عمرو** بن عائذ بن عمران بن مخزوم بن يقظة بن مرة بن كعب بن لؤي بن غالب بن فهر بن مالك بن النضر .
>
> The mother of Abdullah, Abi Talib, Al-Zubayr and **all of his daughters except Safiyyah was Fatimah bint Amr** bin A'idh bin Imran bin Makhzum bin Yaqazah ...
>
> <sup>— [سيرة ابن هشام](https://archive.org/stream/sirat-ibn-hisham-vol-1/sih-v-01#page/n157/mode/2up)</sup>